# How to get only one db record from couple of same?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have records in the db table that can differ only by ids and creation/update time. How can I get only the unique records?
I tried this way, but it didn't work:

```
msg_to_user = user.messages.new_messages.uniq
```

I'll explain. User can follow post manually but also same post can be followed by user automatically. So I want to send only one message if post have been commented by someone.

```
1747    test message    TamadaTours 12  new 2016-01-29 06:14:04.736869  2016-01-29 06:48:55.948529  32964382
1748    test message    TamadaTours 12  new 2016-01-29 06:14:04.741184  2016-01-29 06:48:55.951371  32964382
```

Comment: Records aren't equal since the ID values differ. That's a valid perspective the ORM. If you only need to know the fields except ID then use a custom SELECT with DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All records in the database are uniq (at least because of ID column, which by default has a uniq constraint).

You would want to use [`DISTINCT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp):

```
Model.select('DISTINCT column_name1, column_name2')
```

Comment: but what if I want to get all fields of the record?

Comment: `Model.select('DISTINCT comment_id, group_id')` - it will return only that two fields, am I right? But I need all fields of this record. It can be few more records with same comment_ids and group_ids, but I need only one!

Comment: exactly, so just select all columns (`Model.select('DISTINCT comment_id, group_id', all_other_columns)`), and distinct will make sure to only have those with all uniq values by column

Comment: @nobilik impossible :)

Comment: `msg_to_user = user.messages.new_messages.select(:all_needed_non_unique_fields).distinct` It works this way and it gives to me what I need. As far as I understood it's impossible to do select unique values and distinct non-unique at the same time. Cheers, your answer helps me anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is flawed...

The point of having an `id`... otherwise known as [`primary_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Primary_key)... in a relational database is so that you can actively identify the **unique** records you want:

> A primary key **uniquely** specifies a tuple within a table. In order for an attribute to be a good primary key it must not repeat

---

When you write... "How can I get only the unique records" ... the answer is to pull only the records based on their `id`.

If you refine your question to what you really want...

> I want to send *only **one** message* if post have been commented by someone

--

In other words, you want to pull a collection of unique `user_ids` (no duplicates), to which you can send new messages?

To do this, you can use...

```
@recipients = Message.select(:user_id).distinct #-> all unique user_ids
```

If you're trying to pull the "new" messages for a user, but only show the first (if they're the same), you'll want to use something like the following:

```
@msg_to_user = user.messages.new_messages.uniq(:title)
```

[Ref](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18004)

---

A better pattern to implement would be to validate the uniqueness of new messages:

```
#app/models/message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :message_id } #-> replace message_id with other unique identifier
end
```

This would ensure only one new message is present for a user.

Comment: At the moment another answer do the work for me. But your answer is the one that I should think about! Later I'll change my db architecture.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use group by in your query like this

```
Model.all.group("column_name")
```

Comment: very bad idea to use `.all`

Comment: if you really want to get only 1 record you don't even need to use distinct/grouping, just use .first and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

One way to extract the data but get rid of the ORM context.

```
# maps every record to hash, remove the ID entry and then removes duplicates
msg_to_user = user.messages.new_messages.attributes.map { |e| e.except('ID') }.uniq
```